# Как переместить данные из одной таблицы в другую?

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть данные в таблице `content2` которые нужно перемести в таблицу `content`

**content2:**

```
id, title, category, directions, time, img, author, datetime
```

Comment: Если таблицы content и content2 имеют одинаковую структуру, перечисление полей таблицы content2 не нужно. Если структура отличается, то необходимо указать список полей из таблицы content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into content select * from content2
```

Структуры таблиц должны совпадать.
Если Вы хотите использовать временную таблицу, можно сделать так:

```
create table content as select * from content2;
```

Если структура таблицы content отличается от content2, можно перечислить поля, которые нужно заполнить и поля, из которых данные будут получены.

Comment: можете ещё привести пример, если поля отличаются, в таблицы `content` поле `title` а `content2` это поле `name`

Comment: Если отличаются только названия полей, то все должно сработать. Если отличается порядок полей, то придется их явно перечислять. Если не сработает, можно сделать так: insert into content select id, title as name, category, directions, time, img, author, datetime from content2